# How can I run something on the UI thread from my Application class

Tags: android

I need to run something inside my extends Application class on the UI thread

```
Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //I need to run code here on the main thread
    }
}, 1000);
```

do I need to pass the activity? It will be difficult since I am calling it from multiple activities

Comment: pass the activity, and use `runOnUiThread` if this is about code factorization. Why is this in your application class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods called by Android in the Application class already run on the UI thread (a.k.a 'main' thread).

When in doubt you can use `Thread.currentThread()` to find out.

Remember to avoid doing costly operations on the main thread.

Comment: doesn't  h.postDelayed(new Runnable() create a new thread. i need to call the code from inside the new runnable

Comment: No, it does not create a new thread. The run() method will be called on the main UI thread. The documentation explains this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

Comment: how comes everytime i need to call something like adview from a runnable, i needed to use runOnUiThread

Comment: Because the library probably is invoking your runnable from a background thread.

Answer (score -2):

You need to call runOnUiThread

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
});
```